# jQuery not changing alert messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm making a tip calculator, and everything works fine, but jQuery doesn't change the formula if a different rating has been selected; e.g, poor, good, great..

**jsFiddle Demo** :: http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/g7vAQ/1/

```
        $('#tip').on('click', function(){

            if($('#poor').click && $('#amount').val().length){

                var theAmountVal = $('#amount').val();

                    alert(theAmountVal * .10);

            } else if($('#good').click && $('#amount').val().length){

                var theAmountVal = $('#amount').val();

                    alert(theAmountVal * .15);

            } else if($('#great').click && $('#amount').val().length){

                var theAmountVal = $('#amount').val();

                    alert(theAmountVal * .20);

            } else {

                    alert("An error has occured.");

            }
```

Comment: I don't think `$("#poor").click` means what you think it means... You might want to have a variable that stores whether "poor", "good", or "great" was clicked and use that instead of `$("#poor").click`

Comment: I would suggest you make your options "poor", "good" and "great" radio buttons and then check for the value that is selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:
**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wDbKw/2/)**

```
var choice;
$('h1').on('click', function () {
    choice = this.id;
    $(this).addClass('active-state').siblings('h1').removeClass('active-state');
});
$('#tip').on('click', function () {
    if (choice == 'poor' && $('#amount').val().length) {
        var theAmountVal = $('#amount').val();
        alert(theAmountVal * .10);
    } else if (choice == 'good' && $('#amount').val().length) {
        var theAmountVal = $('#amount').val();
            alert(theAmountVal * .15);
    } else if (choice == 'great' && $('#amount').val().length) {
            var theAmountVal = $('#amount').val();
        alert(theAmountVal * .20);
    } else {
        alert("An error has occured.");
    }
});
```

I got the `id` of the clicked option and stored it in a `variable`, then I used your code and re-check the `id` on the `if` statements.

Comment: Thanks man, that works nicely!  I'm a little confused to what id does.  My guess is that 'id' represents h1, and in the if statements, it checks if the id of the h1 is poor, good, or great?

Comment: @MattKnowsTech, id is a unique identifier you can have in a html tag. Very useful to make it unique. With `.prop` I read the property `id` of the item clicked which you do by calling `$('this')` and stored it in a variable.

Comment: @Sergio, why not just `choice = this.id;`?

Comment: @Sergio what i am saying is, dont use prop, use `this.id` same result, but it is faster than prop : http://jsfiddle.net/wDbKw/1/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon , yes, sure, even better. Good point! +1 for making life more simple :)

Answer (score 3):

That's not really how `.click` work...

`.click` is a function triggering a click or adding a event binding.

You should try this condition (x3 adapted for other elements):

```
if($('#poor').hasClass('active-state')&& $('#amount').val().length)
```

`.hasClass` will check if it has class and return true or false.

Here's the doc for `.hasClass()`: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Also, if i can give you an advice, you can add the factor in a custom attribute like that :

```
<h1 id="poor" data-factor='.10' data-clicked="false">Poor</h1>
<h1 id="good" data-factor='.15' data-clicked="false">Good</h1>
<h1 id="great" data-factor='.20' data-clicked="false">Great</h1>
```

and reduce you code to that :

```
$('h1').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active-state').siblings('h1').removeClass('active-state');
});

$('#tip').on('click', function(){
    if($('.active-state').length && $('#amount').val().length){
        var theAmountVal = $('#amount').val();
        alert(theAmountVal * $('.active-state').data('factor'));
    }

});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g7vAQ/5/

Comment: @MattKnowsTech Updated my answer, adding a little optimisation.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var theAmountVal=0;

        jQuery('#tip').onclick(function(){

            if($('#poor').click && $('#amount').val().length){

                theAmountVal = $('#amount').val();

                    alert(parseInt(theAmountVal)* .10);

            } else if($('#good').click && $('#amount').val().length){

                theAmountVal = $('#amount').val();

                    alert(parseInt(theAmountVal)* .15);

            } else if($('#great').click && $('#amount').val().length){

                theAmountVal = $('#amount').val();

                    alert(parseInt(theAmountVal)* .20);

            } else {

                    alert("An error has occured.");

            }

});
```

And remove this `$('#good').click` From code, replace it with something else.
.Click - is event, and can't be used in IF..ELSE structure